# collect2:error in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I just installed Qt and I created a console project and printed hello world and it printed that out perfectly. I also added opencv libraries to the same project and was able to load an image successfully. Then i created a new project as qt widget application project and without making any changes  to the project (which comes with the main window class and main source file) I run it the following error pops up.

> error: cannot find -lGL
>
> error: collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

what do I do?
my .pro file

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2015-03-15T17:46:46  
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = untitled
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

Comment: This is strange indeed but post .pro file. There might be something wrong in it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this. Apparently it depends upon the libgl1-mesa-dev package. So install the package and restart Qt .  I have ubuntu 14.04.02 and it showed some errors when I tried installing in the conventional way

> sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev

So I tried

> sudo aptitude install libgl1-mesa-dev

That didn't work well either. A different website showed a way around it

> sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-dev-lts-utopic mesa-common-dev-lts-utopic libxatracker-dev-lts-utopic libopenvg1-mesa-dev-lts-utopic libgles2-mesa-dev-lts-utopic libgles1-mesa-dev-lts-utopic libgl1-mesa-dev-lts-utopic libgbm-dev-lts-utopic libegl1-mesa-dev-lts-utopic

This installed properly. Now when I restarted Qt it worked properly.
for your reference:

http://xrong.org/notes/install-Qt-OpenCV-Ubuntu

http://answers.ros.org/question/203610/ubuntu-14042-unmet-dependencies/